# Apple Store URL available before app approval?

Tags: url, app-store, app-store-connect

I am developing an app with some sections were I need an email to be generated with the link to the Apple Store URL for my app.

Is there a way to have it before the App is on the store for the first time or not, so as I have to wait for the first release and then add the link to the app in a second version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the link to your app inside iTunesConnect. The link does not work till it is live for the first time, but you can rest assured that the link Apple provides you will be the definite link.

You may find the link: iTunesConnect login --> My apps --> Choose your app --> (menu bar) More --> Watch  in the App Store.

I attach a screenshot here:

[image]

Notice:
1. The app I show has never been live but the link appears nevertheless
2. Sorry for the Spanish (instead of English) text in the image, but iTunesConnect has just translated contents.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. However, when I select Watch in the App Store from More in iTunes Connect, after a few seconds I get the msg "the item you have requested is not currently available on the Apple Store"... any tip please???

Comment: That's it. Because the app won't be available till Apple approves it. But when they do, then the link, that exact link, will work.

Comment: Exactly, but how can I link it inside my App then if the App has to be submitted already and approved before knowing it?

Comment: You need to use the link though it won't work till the app goes live. It will work, or at least it's always worked for all the devs. When you link to the appstore asking for a review, you also need to provide a link to the app. It works just the same.

Comment: Sorry but maybe I am not clear enough with the question: can I get that link without uploading my App/binary? Everything is set up in my iTunes Connect except the App binary, but there is no link available. If I click to More\View in the AppStore, I get a msg saying that the app does not exist. So I cannot retrieve any link... Do you mean that although I get that msg I can copy the temporary Safari link and that will be the link??! :)

Comment: The Preview on App Store link is now at the bottom under app Store Connect, App Information (left), Additional Information